# Using Lookup function if it contains any function in SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have to define a lookup like this in my *.rdl file;

```
=IIF(Parameters!CompanyId.Value<>67,IIF(LAST(Fields!GallonsPumped.Value)>0, 0, " "),
Lookup(Fields!TankDateCombo.Value, Fields!TankDateCombo.Value,IIF(LAST(Fields!GallonsPumped.Value)>0, 0, " "),"Dataset2"))
```

But I get error saying that I canot use functions in LOOKUp. How can I do this in correctway>

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed like this(surrounding lookup with function name)
eg:

```
=IIF(Parameters!CompanyId.Value<>67, IIF(LAST(Fields!GallonsPumped.Value)>0, 0, " "),

IIF(LAST(Lookup(Fields!TankDateCombo.Value, Fields!TankDateCombo.Value,Fields!GallonsPumped.Value,"Dataset2"))>0, 0, " ")


)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax (match `Table2` on `Table1`):

```
=Lookup(Fields!KeyTable1.Value, Fields!KeyTable2.Value, Fields!DisplayValueTable2, "Table2DatasetName")
```

`Lookup()` just matches a `1:1` relationship, if you have a `1:n` you need to use `LookupSet()`. If `Lookup()` doesnt find a match it returns `Nothing`.

Comment: Here I think, the error says I canot use LAST () function in Lookup.  How can i modify my query?

Comment: Well it doenst make sense to use the `Last()` function in the `Lookup()`. With a `Lookup()` you join two tables and display a value from the second table which meets the join criterias (keys). What you do is to join and then display always the result of the `Last()` function. For this you dont need to `Lookup()`. You should be able to do this without a `Lookup()` by just using `Last()`. Depending on your scope or desired needs this can be done without a `Lookup()`.